# Video to Panorama in Android

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android

Is it possible to convert video to panorama in android using  FFmpeg?

I have found below command from this [https://github.com/ibaaj/awesome-OpenSourcePhotography#video-to-panorama](https://github.com/ibaaj/awesome-OpenSourcePhotography#video-to-panorama/)

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 5 -qscale 3  tmp/images/image-%3d.jpg
pto_gen -o tmp/hugin.pto tmp/images/*.jpg
cpfind --multirow -o tmp/hugin.pto tmp/hugin.pto
cpclean -o tmp/hugin.pto tmp/hugin.pto
linefind -o tmp/hugin.pto tmp/hugin.pto
autooptimiser -a -l -s -m -o tmp/hugin.pto tmp/hugin.pto
pano_modify -o tmp/hugin.pto --center --fov=AUTO --canvas=70% tmp/hugin.pto
pto2mk -o tmp/hugin.mk -p tmp/output tmp/hugin.pto
make -f tmp/hugin.mk all
```

Any idea how can I use this for Android or any other helpful command, it would be very helpful !!!

Answer (score 1):

While that command may well be the right one to convert video to panorama in ffmpeg, you don't get ffmpeg by default on Android.

You can get a version from the [SourceForge FFmpeg for Android project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/), but I'll warn you that compilation may have its challenges. We have an [old question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) on this. Top answer there gives some detail on these headings:

- Build static libraries of ffmpeg for Android.
- Create a dynamic library wrapping ffmpeg functionality using the Android NDK.
- Use the ffmpeg-wrapping dynamic library from your java sources.

Any questions on the technical implementation / compilation aspects should be raised over on Stack Overflow (or possibly Android Stack Exchange)